# Openshift Billing payments

Tags: openshift

How it works the billing for openshift services?
For example..

If i have free plan (3 gears) and update for bronze and say that my application will use min:1 and max:3, it still free,right?

But if i say min:1 and max:4, i will pay for 1 gear small,right?
So, where i can say how many time it will be up? I mean the small gear that im paying..
And when they will charge for it? On last day from this month? Or per day?

For this example, they will charge 0.48 perday ?

Sorry for a lot of questions, but seems confunse on openshift page

Answer (score 0):

This question does not seem suitable for StackOverflow, you may want to [contact Red Hat customer service](https://access.redhat.com/support/contact/customerService/) for details on OpenShift Online billing...

---

One of your questions seems to be answered [here](https://www.openshift.com/pricing/index.html#faq-billing), in the "*Billing*" FAQ section, under "*When do you charge my credit card?*".

Other than that, the three small gears are free with all plans, every additional small gear would cost $0.02 for every hour it is created ([how scaling up and down works?](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/scaling.html#how-scaling-works)), monthly usage is detailed in invoices and in the web console.

Answer (score 0):

**Anwswering One by One**

> How it works the billing for OpenShift services?

Its very well explained for each **type of gear** used by your application at [OpenShift Plans and Pricing Page](https://www.openshift.com/pricing/index.html).

> What are gears?

Gears are secure containers for your code. Each gear is allocated CPU, memory, disk, and network bandwidth. You can use a single gear to create an entire web application complete with a private database instance. Use multiple gears to create multiple applications or configure your applications to automatically scale in response to web traffic. [Source](https://www.openshift.com/pricing/index.html)

> If i have free plan (3 gears) and update for bronze and say that my application will use min:1 and max:3, it still free,right?

**Yes**, it will be free upto 3 small basic gears. These free gears are included in every plan. So you will be charged **$0/hour** in bronze if you use only 3 small basic gears.

> But if i say min:1 and max:4, i will pay for 1 gear small,right?

**Depends on which gear is used.** You will pay for 1 small basic gear if it is used for 4th gear. If you created application using production gears, you will be charged accordingly.

> So, where i can say how many time it will be up? I mean the small gear that im paying.. And when they will charge for it? On last day from this month? Or per day?

**You will be charged for the resources used and not for the uptime.** Meaning you will be charged for the gears used in application even when application is idle, as resources are still attached to the application.

Comment: need anything more , feel free to comment.